# Change App name on App Store (iTunes Connect)

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

How do I change a app name on App Store?
This app is already for sale.

I saw in anothers posts that there is a edit button in version details screen, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only change the name when you submit an update.